# Ubuntu 18.10 CPU1 always around 100% despite no programs are running

Tags: intel, 18.10, cpu, overheating, cpu-load

I'm new user who transitioned from Windows and I have this nasty problem 
since I installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my HP ProBook 450 with I3-6100 with 2 core and 4 threads my CPU 1 is around 100% and CPU 2,3,4 are <10%. My laptop is overheating and fan is always on...
Unfortunately haven't found anyone with this kind of problem.
[This is Htop picture of no programs running:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwFqP.png)

I've seen people suggest running update and upgrade, but haven't helped me.
As far as I checked all drivers are up to date.

Update 1:

output of: *grep -i aer /var/log/syslog** https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GP6ZDXKZGQ/

output of: *grep -i ata /var/log/syslog**
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G6sFDrrfs7/

output of: *grep -i sda /var/log/syslog**
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5Hs9tMbQJH/

output of: *dpkg -l *selinux** 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZPcDyQF7Hz/

output of: *dpkg -l *armor** 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jqnshxH7Fk/

output of: *ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-sh*
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gjyd898xYH/

error of updating GPU Driver from site:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r7-series/amd-radeon-r7-300-series/amd-radeon-r7-m340

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer _64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer _64a:none:5.0.8-050008-generic:)

Comment: htop certainly isn't giving us a clue. How about `top`?

Comment: here u go https://imgur.com/qwmXuX5

Comment: there it is. Lets try and get more details... `grep -i acpi /var/log/syslog*` and post that output to paste.ubuntu.com. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: ok @heynnema, I've done what You said. Here is the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5GyrjVt5JK/

Comment: Please see my quick answer... check/do the BIOS update first. The acpi patch may come later... report back.

Answer (score 1):

We may have a HP BIOS/ACPI problem.

1. **Lets check the BIOS first...**

In `terminal` type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and note the output.

Compare the output with this...

[image]

If your BIOS is older, go to [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-450-g1-notebook-pc/5405421) to download the new BIOS.

**Note**: backup your important data before installing the new BIOS.

Install the new BIOS.

Monitor the top CPU processes, looking for `kacpid`, using the `top` command in the `terminal`.

2. **Kernel ACPI patch...**

If you tried these steps before I had completed the instructions, then do this command:

`sudo rm -i /etc/default/xxxx` # delete this unnecessary file

Then continue...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit grub defaults

Find and change:

```
"quiet splash"
```

to:

<strike>"quiet splash acpi=strict"</strike>

`sudo update-grub` # update grub

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` # update initramfs

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Monitor the top CPU processes, looking for `kacpid`, using the `top` command in the `terminal`.

**Update #1:**

To solve the current boot problem...

If you have ANY problems with this procedure, contact me immediately.

- at the GRUB menu...
- hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
- using the arrow keys, find "quiet splash pnpacpi=off" and change it to "quiet splash"
- hit the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, or <kbd>F10</kbd> key to continue to boot
- once booted, repeat Step #2 in my answer, and change "quiet splash pnpacpi=off" back to just "quiet splash", and do the follow-on commands
- you should be able to reboot normally

**Update #2:**

notes to self... not complete yet...

`colord` errors, install snmp-mibs-downloader

`SECURITY FREEZE LOCK` occurs on all SATA HDD

`SELinux` causing errors, check apparmor, uninstall

`gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0` crashing system, GNOME extensions or video driver?

`/home/sharich/drive/FER` what is in this folder?

`indicator-cpufreq: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0` crashing system

`blueman-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0` crashing system

`pulseaudio[2304]: XIO:  fatal IO error 1 (Operation not permitted) on X server ":0` crashing system

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92729/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-18-10-cpu1-always-around-100-despite-no).